# cordova build android give error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am new to cordova. I have successfully created my first project using

`cordova create FirstProject com.phonegappro.hello HelloWorld`

`cordova platform add android`

`cordova build android` I am getting following error.

```
D:\wamp\www\FirstProject>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Santosh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

what I am doing wrong ?
I have android studio installed. phonegab and cordova are latest with Node js higher v6.10.2

Comment: Do both paths actually exist? (C:\Users\Santosh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131)

Comment: yes. both the path exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the Gradle. Previously I had uninstalled android studio. And now again when I install it there was two folder for Android studio. `Android Studio` and `Android Studio 1` by default it was trying to access the Gradle inside the `Android Studio` which was empty. I deleted it and renamed the `Android Studio 1` to `Android Studio`.

path : `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`

It worked for me.